# Subtraction using different columns in multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have two dicts, one with three columns (A) and another with six columns (B), I would like to be able to use the value in the first column (index which is constant for both 1-4) and also the value in the second column (1-2000) to specify the correct element in the third column for subtraction. The second dict is similar in that the first and second columns are used to find the correct row however it is the value in the sixth column of that row that is needed for the subtraction.

```
A                                   B
1  1  260   541                     1  1  260   280   0.001  521.4
1  1  390   1195                    1  1  390   900   0.02   963.3
1  1  102   6                       1  1  102   2     0.01   4.8
2  1  65    12                      2  1  65    9     0.13   13.1
2  1  515   659                     2  1  515   356   0.002  532.2
2  1  354   1200                    2  1  354   1087  0.119  1502.3
3  1  1190  53                      3  1  1190  46    0.058  12.0
3  1  1985  3                       3  1  1985  1     0.006  1.02
3  1  457   192                     3  1  25    3     0.001  178.2
4  1  261   2084                    4  1  261   1792  0.196  100.7
4  1  12    0                       4  1  12    0     0.000  12.6
4  1  1756  30                      4  1  1756  28    0.006  23.7
4  1  592   354                     4  1  592   291   0.357  251.9
```

So basically I would like to subtract the last column of B from the last column of A whilst retaining the information held in the first and second columns.

```
C         (desired output)                       
1  1  260   19.6
1  1  390   231.7
1  1  102   1.2
2  1  65    -1.1
2  1  515   126.8
2  1  354   -302.3
3  1  1190  41.0
3  1  1985  1.98
3  1  457   13.8
4  1  261   1983.3
4  1  12    -12.6
4  1  1756  6.3
4  1  592   102.1
```

I have been through SO for hours looking for a solution but havent found a solution as of yet but I'm sure it must be possible.
I need to be able to create a scatter graph afterwards as well in case anyone has any suggestions as to how to plot positive values and ignore the negatives.

EDIT:
I have added my code below to make it clearer, I take in a three column csv file and then need to get a count of the frequency of each value of the third column when they have the same value in the first column. B then has further alterations to get out the desired data streams and then the subtraction needs to be made. In a few of the comments it mentioned that column one and two are unnecessary but the value in column three is linked to the value in column one and thus must always remain in the same row together.
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

```
def ba(fn, float1, float2):
    ba=pd.read_csv(fn,header=None, skipfooter=6, engine='python')
    ba['col4']=ba.groupby(['col1','col3']).transform(np.size)
    ba['col5']=ba['col4'].apply(lambda x: x/float(float2)) 
    ba['col6']=ba['col5'].apply(lambda x: x*float1)
    ba=ba.set_index('col1')
    ba = dict(tuple(ba.groupby('col1')))
    return ba
```

Comment: You mean dicts or dataframes?

Comment: Is your data in a dataframe already?

Comment: I don't understand what the first two columns have to do with anything

Comment: The data is in a dict, I did have it in a dataframe but in order to sort by the value of the first column I had to use a dict. Apologies, I should have mentioned above the first column is needed for the plotting later as each value will be on a separate plot. Take the data as being in a dict and grouped by the value in the first column, I then need to find corresponding values from the third column that is in a different order in each (I should have shown that above) and then subtract as you have shown below. Your answer is correct but I need to be able to match the first and third columns too

Answer (score 0):

IIUIC, `A` and `B` are dataframes then

```
In [1062]: A.iloc[:, :3].assign(output=A.iloc[:, -1] - B.iloc[:, -1])
Out[1062]:
    0  1     2   output
0   1  1   260    19.60
1   1  1   390   231.70
2   1  1   102     1.20
3   2  1    65    -1.10
4   2  1   515   126.80
5   2  1   354  -302.30
6   3  1  1190    41.00
7   3  1  1985     1.98
8   3  1   457    13.80
9   4  1   261  1983.30
10  4  1    12   -12.60
11  4  1  1756     6.30
12  4  1   592   102.10
```

Details

```
In [1063]: A
Out[1063]:
    0  1     2     3
0   1  1   260   541
1   1  1   390  1195
2   1  1   102     6
3   2  1    65    12
4   2  1   515   659
5   2  1   354  1200
6   3  1  1190    53
7   3  1  1985     3
8   3  1   457   192
9   4  1   261  2084
10  4  1    12     0
11  4  1  1756    30
12  4  1   592   354

In [1064]: B
Out[1064]:
    0  1     2     3      4        5
0   1  1   260   280  0.001   521.40
1   1  1   390   900  0.020   963.30
2   1  1   102     2  0.010     4.80
3   2  1    65     9  0.130    13.10
4   2  1   515   356  0.002   532.20
5   2  1   354  1087  0.119  1502.30
6   3  1  1190    46  0.058    12.00
7   3  1  1985     1  0.006     1.02
8   3  1    25     3  0.001   178.20
9   4  1   261  1792  0.196   100.70
10  4  1    12     0  0.000    12.60
11  4  1  1756    28  0.006    23.70
12  4  1   592   291  0.357   251.90
```